# Verify if iphone was connected to a dock

Tags: iphone, ios, dock, mpvolumeview

When I connect the iphone to a dock my app display the message: "Conector dock". I want to detect when the phone is connected with other device and hide the MPVolumeView to avoid those messages.

I am using MPVolumeView as the usual:

```
MPVolumeView *myVolume = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 435, 300, 0)];
[myVolume sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:myVolume];
[myVolume release];
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did that by adding the observers that follow:

```
NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
EAAccessoryManager *accessoryMamaner  = [EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager];

[accessoryMamaner registerForLocalNotifications];
[notificationCenter addObserver: self  selector: @selector (accessoryDidConnect:)   name: EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification object: nil];
[notificationCenter addObserver: self  selector: @selector (accessoryDidDisconnect:)   name: EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification object: nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could monitor the battery state.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryState] != UIDeviceBatteryStateUnplugged) {
    // if you end up in here, then you are connected to some power source
    // and you can hide your MPVolumeView
}
```

More information about the battery state can be found at [Apple's UIDevice documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: In this case when I plug the phone to a computer this will cause the MPVolumeView stay hidden. I do not want this behaviour.

Comment: Your question is confusing then. I am not certain what you are trying to do.

Comment: A dock is a external device that I can plug the phone to provide some extra features. There are docks to play music with external speakers, charge the phone, among other features. Usualy you plug the phone directly without the usb cable.

Comment: Actually, docs are usually connected to the 12-pin-connector (or USB-thingy), which triggers this battery state.